# Export as Table with alignment?

Tags: export, list-manipulation

I have a table in Mathematica as a list of lists.

How to export the table, and force Mathematica to insert as many spaces as needed between columns so that columns are aligned?

For example,

```
Export["~/Desktop/test.txt", {{2334252, 1}, {2, 235211234}}, "Table"]
```

gives a misaligned table. The misalignment depends on the tab size of your editor

Comment: How about adding some sample data?

Comment: @YvesKlett I added an example. How bad the misalignment looks depends on the tab size, of course.

Comment: Any preference for the aligning (left/center/right)?

Comment: @YvesKlett I just found a way to do it and posted an answer. However, ideally I would like to specify different alignments for different columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
Export["~/Desktop/test.txt", {{2334252, 1}, {2, 235211234}}, "Table",
  "FieldSeparators"->" ", Alignment->Left]
```

Instead of `Left` you can also use `Center`/`Right`. The options for `Export` with different formats aren't very easy to find in the documentation!